# Inkscape make visible filter color permanent

Tags: inkscape, transparency

Let's say I have a rectangle with filter applied and a, alpha different from FF(255) making it transparent.

On a white background in inkscape it looks great and these are the colours that I want to use.

I export the image as a .PNG file and when using the .PNG on a website with a different background (not white) the colors are different.

How can I make the colors that I see in inkscape on a white background permanent? So not transparent, but still with the areas around it transparent?

Hope someone understands what I try to say. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you like the light blue on the transparent star, but not its transparency. You can use the Color Pick tool (F7) to transfer just that light blue color (excluding the transparency) to a duplicate object. First select your  duplicate object then click on Color Pick tool and, before clicking on the light blue color to pick it, first unselect "Pick" in the opacity option of the tool:
[image]

Then you can now click on the light blue. Only that light blue, not its transparency, will be transferred to your duplicate. This works even if your duplicate is also transparent – you'll end up with an opaque object. This also works even if you don't have a duplicate: just select your transparent object, click with the Color Pick tool ("Pick" option unselected) on your desired color area, and your previously transparent star will become opaque.
[image]

To keep the transparency around your object when exporting, make sure there is no background nor other objects inside its bounding box before doing the export to PNG.
[image]

Comment: Is there no easier method as my image contains many lines and if I have to do this all manually I'll be done next week.

Answer (score 0):

Make an opaque, white rectangle of the page size, and put it down as the lowest layer.